# Calculate Number Of Days In A Specified Month

Tags: objective-c, ios7, nscalendar

In iOS I want to calculate the number of days in a month specified by the month name as an NSString.

I can get the number of days in the current month as follows:

```
-(NSUInteger) getNumberOfDaysInMonth:(NSString *)monthName
{

NSCalendar *cal = [NSCalendar ];
NSRange rng = [cal rangeOfUnit:NSDayCalendarUnit inUnit:NSMonthCalendarUnit forDate:[NSDate date]];
NSUInteger numberOfDaysInMonth = rng.length;

return numberOfDaysInMonth;

}
```

Is there an elegant way to get the month when I know the month name in objective c?

Comment: Look into NSDateFormatter and use the patterns described [here](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date_Format_Patterns). Note that there are many ways to represent a month as a string. Consider "September", "Sept", "S", "09", "9", "Sep", "The month before October".

Answer (score 0):

For example, you can use :

```
  NSDateFormatter* formatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
  [formatter setDateFormat:@"MMM"];
  NSDate *aDate = [formatter dateFromString:@"Aug"];
  NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSMonthCalendarUnit fromDate:aDate];
  NSLog(@"Month: %i", [components month]);
```

or :

```
  ...
  [formatter setDateFormat:@"MMMM"];
  NSDate *aDate = [formatter dateFromString:@"August"];
  ...
```

Comment: I am not near a Mac to try out your code, but what does it output for Feb?  Because I am thinking you would need the year also.

Comment: the code just return the int corresponding to the month, no need to add day or year to do that.

Comment: It would be good to know how to get the number of days in a specified month in a specified year too.